# Solve for non-linear equation but minimise the difference vs initial input

Tags: python, scipy, solver

I am looking to find the values for x and y given the below formula (portfolio risk). The code does give me a result, but the problem has several solutions (i.e. more than one combination of `x` and `y` can solve the equation).

I am only interested in the solution closest to `x0`. For instance, assume, x0 = 0.45 and there are solutions that exist for `x = 0.40` and `x = 0.35`. I want the solver to return `x = 0.40`. In effect I want a solution that minimises the difference between `x` and `x0` [minimise absolute (x-x0)].

Thank you in advance for helping.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve`

def f(x) :`

    port_risk = 0.06
    sd_EQ = 0.25
    sd_FI = 0.07
    Cor = -0.1
    return ((sd_EQ**2)*(x**2) + (sd_FI**2)*(y**2) + 2*Cor*sd_EQ*sd_FI*x*y)**0.5 - port_risk


x0 = 0.45354
print ("x = ", x)
print ("y = ", y)
print ("f(x) =", f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a constrained optimization problem, you can solve it with the [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function from [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    port_risk = 0.06
    sd_EQ = 0.25
    sd_FI = 0.07
    Cor = -0.1
    return ((sd_EQ**2)*(x[0]**2) + (sd_FI**2)*(x[1]**2) + 2*Cor*sd_EQ*sd_FI*x[0]*x[1])**0.5 - port_risk

# Defining the objective function
def obj_fun(x, x0_start):
    return np.abs(x[0] - x0_start)

# Defining the constraint: f(x) = 0
cons = ({"type": "eq", "fun": f})

# Solving the constrained optimization problem.
x0_s = 0.45354
res = minimize(obj_fun, args=(x0_s,), x0=[x0_s, 0], constraints=cons)
print(f"x={res.x[0]}")
print(f"y={res.x[1]}")
```

PS: I rewrote your function f to emphasize that it's a function of two variables.